# Issue with replacing floats in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have the following string:

```
'd="M4.125,4 L4.25,1 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L7.5,4.25 L4.5,4.375 L4.375,4.5 L4.25,7.5 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L1,4.25 L4,4.125z" d="M4.125,4 L4.25,2.5 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L6,4.25 L4.5,4.375 L4.375,4.5 L4.25,6 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L2.5,4.25 L4,4.125z"'
```

I need to extract all numbers (`float` and `int`), multiply them by `5` and replace them with the result.

So I tried doing the following:

```
var x = 'd="M4.125,4 L4.25,1 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L7.5,4.25 L4.5,4.375 L4.375,4.5 L4.25,7.5 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L1,4.25 L4,4.125z" d="M4.125,4 L4.25,2.5 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L6,4.25 L4.5,4.375 L4.375,4.5 L4.25,6 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L2.5,4.25 L4,4.125z"'
var reg = /(\d\.*\d{0,3})/g
var match = x.match(reg);

for (i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
    x = x.replace(new RegExp(match[i], 'g'), match[i] * 5)
}

console.log(match)
console.log(x)
```

The regex is fine. It extracts all numbers. The problem is with the `.replace()` function.

It logs this for `match`:

```
Array [ "4.125", "4", "4.25", "1", "4.375", "4", "4.5", "4.125", "7.5", "4.25", 38 more… ]
```

And this for `x`:

```
"d="M20.3025,20 L20.25,5 L20.375,20 L20.5,20.3025 L337.5,20.25 L20.5,20.375 L20.375,20.5 L20.25,337.5 L20.3025,20.5 L20,20.375 L5,20.25 L20,20.3025z" d="M20.3025,20 L20.25,112.5 L20.375,20 L20.5,20.3025 L30,20.25 L20.5,20.375 L20.375,20.5 L20.25,30 L20.3025,20.5 L20,20.375 L112.5,20.25 L20,20.3025z""
     ^^^^^^^     ^^^^^    ^^^^^^     ^^^^ ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^ ^^^^^
```

As you can see the first number is `20.3025` but I expected it to be `20.625`.

The numbers in string `x` should be replaced by the following numbers.

```
Array [ 20.625, 20, 21.25, 5, 21.875, 20, 22.5, 20.625, 37.5, 21.25, 38 more… ]
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, please let me know if there is any easy way to doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you use a loop for the match elements. With it you where repeating the replace action for `x` for *every match element*. Every iteration of the loop is applied to a *changed* `x` string, so the final result is not what you expected.

It works if you convert te value of `match[i]` to `Number`, and use a more direct/simpler approach for replacing the numbers in your string.

```js
var x = 'd="M4.125,4 L4.25,1 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L7.5,4.25 L4.5,4.375 '+
        'L4.375,4.5 L4.25,7.5 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L1,4.25 L4,4.125z" '+
        'd="M4.125,4 L4.25,2.5 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L6,4.25 L4.5,4.375 '+
        'L4.375,4.5 L4.25,6 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L2.5,4.25 L4,4.125z"';
var reg = /(\d\.*\d{0,3})/g
var match = x.match(reg);
var report = document.querySelector('#result');

report.innerHTML = 'x initially: '+x+'<hr>';

// a more simple approach
x = x.replace(reg, function(a) {return +a * 5;});

report.innerHTML += 'x after: '+x + '<hr>match: '+match.join(', ');
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: [It still doesn't solve the problem, if you use the whole string `'d="M4.125,4 L4.25,1 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L7.5,4.25 L4.5,4.375 L4.375,4.5 L4.25,7.5 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L1,4.25 L4,4.125z" d="M4.125,4 L4.25,2.5 L4.375,4 L4.5,4.125 L6,4.25 L4.5,4.375 L4.375,4.5 L4.25,6 L4.125,4.5 L4,4.375 L2.5,4.25 L4,4.125z"'`](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/0s78vovu/)

Comment: My code works even if I don't convert the number to `Number`(`+`), if I use the string that you've used. ----------> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/0s78vovu/1/)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: try `x = x.replace(reg, function(a, b) {return +a * 5;});`, see http://jsfiddle.net/1dap7o85/

Comment: Great! Thanks! that worked. I don't get it. Why was it doing that?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py: glad I could help. Not sure why 'it' was doing that, but I have to catch a train now. Maybe I'll look into it later, I think it has something to do with the match result array

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I've added an explanation to the answer